# Error using Firebase from Chrome App

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-app

I am attempting to use Firebase from within a Chrome App (not an extension) and have not been able to work around the following error:

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://{my firebase id}.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=81980096&cb=15&v=5'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that
>   'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

my manifest.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Simple Demo",
  "version": "1",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["https://*.firebaseio.com/"],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "28"
}
```

I have the firebase.js script local to the chrome app, the issue seems to be that it tries to load other scripts which isn't permitted.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the content security policy  `{
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'"
}` in your manifest?

Comment: I did try that and just tried again to be sure, doesn't help, think that setting only applies to chrome extensions, not chrome apps.

Comment: Ok I see. I think you need to download the script and put it into the Chrome App folder instead of loading the script directly from the web.

Comment: It is the firebase.js script which I do have local that is attempting to download other scripts that is causing the problem it seems.

Comment: Yes. You need to download all scripts in your local Chrome app folder instead of loading them from the web.

Comment: You may need to go [the sandbox route](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sencha_framework). (That ExtJS is just an example tutorial)

Comment: I have the same problem, and it doesn't look like there is a solution for this. The only workaround I've seen so far is the sandboxing that @Xan proposed, but that's kind of going against the simplicity of Firebase because you'll need an intermediate layer.

Comment: Even after using sandbox, we face issue and it says
Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "chrome-extension://mgfdmgicmfnpdfddkicoenaebgdoddaa" from accessing a frame at "null".  Both frames are sandboxed and lack the "allow-same-origin" flag.
This is because 'internally' new firebase sdk tries to do document.open() with which chrome app is not happy to allow!

Comment: And as per https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated there is no workaround for document.open().

Answer (score 1):

Well, You can use firebase REST API Approach, in this case, I've used for my chrome app and its working fine. This don't require to have firebase SDK to be added!

Read the following docs,
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/03/announcing-streaming-for-firebase-rest.html

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data

Approach is very simple

Protocol is known as [SSE (Server Sent Events)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) where you listen to specific server URL and when something changes, you get the event callback.

In this case, firebase officially provides SSE based mechanism

A sample code snippet is,

```
 //firebaseUrl will be like https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/yourNode.json or https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/yourNode/.json
 //notice ".json" at the end of URL, whatever node you want to listen, add .json as suffix
    var firebaseEventSS = new EventSource(firebaseUrl);
    //and you will have callbacks where you get the data
    firebaseEventSS.addEventListener("patch", function (e) {
                var data = e.data;
            }, false);
    firebaseEventSS.addEventListener("put", function (e) {
                var data = e.data;
            }, false);
```

Just check few [EventSource examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) and combine with Firebase Doc for REST API and you are all set!

Don't forget to close() when it's done.

```
firebaseEventSS.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but the solution offered by the Firebase team is to use a different URL protocol for the database.

So instead of using `https://<app>.firebaseio.com/` you'd use `wss://<app>.firebaseio.com/`.

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/82). Here [is an answer provided by the Firebase team on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937825/how-can-i-force-firebase-realtime-database-to-use-websockets/44937826#44937826).