# Chrome Packaged app with Firebase

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to use firebase with chrome packaged app?

I am getting following error on calling `new Firebase()`

```
it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". 
Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399594/error-using-firebase-from-chrome-app, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624106/is-it-possible-to-have-a-chrome-packaged-app-that-utilizes-firebase and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569565/firebase-not-getting-loaded-in-chrome-extension-content-script

Comment: Hi, I am able to connect to firebase db, if I call Firebase.INTERNAL.forceWebSockets(); before calling new Firebase. Not sure why its not working directly.

Comment: Cool. So by embedding the Firebase JavaScript library in your app and calling `forceWebSockets()` you got it working? Sounds like an answer! :-)

Comment: Some features are working some are not. Like, User session is lost on app restart.

Comment: Hey,
from new version of firebase we don't do new Firebase(), in such case how can we solve this error?

Comment: This might help you,

http://stackoverflow.com/a/42153075/1151625